# Chat right alignment issue on Samsung Galazy s3 API 18

Tags: android, android-layout, alignment

I am developing an android application that also implements a chat but I am facing a weird issue on a galaxy s3 device running api 18.
s the image clearly show the text aligned on the right isn't well formatted as it should be on a single line. The layout file is as simple as possibile and no issue is shown on other phones and emulators.

[Issue Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3U04.jpg)

Here is my xml layout file:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textMine"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:visibility="visible" >
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/silh"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/profilePicMine"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:focusable="false" />
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/profilePicMine"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/profilePicMine"
            android:id="@+id/nuvolaMine">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
                android:src="@drawable/home_pic"
                android:id="@+id/picMine"/>
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/chat_yellow"
                android:paddingRight="15dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:id="@+id/textLayoutMine"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp">
            <com.sonarmusic.robotoTextViews.RobotoRegularTextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:text="non so"
                android:id="@+id/textMessageMine" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/profilePicMine"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/profilePicMine"
            android:src="@drawable/verde_on"
            android:id="@+id/isArtistMine"/>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="5dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@color/chat_yellow"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
        </RelativeLayout>
        <com.sonarmusic.robotoTextViews.RobotoLightTextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="6sp"
            android:textColor="@color/gray_text"
            android:text="08-08-2016"
            android:id="@+id/timeMine"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/nuvolaMine"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/nuvolaMine" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

To me it looks like an issue due to right alignment that either android api 18 or both os and device can't render well, another reason why I have this thought is that the texts on the left side(the received ones in green background) are formatted the right way. But I have no clue on how possibily solve it.

PS Not supporting that device is NOT an option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

by

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

in your RelativeLayouts

Comment: I rewrote the layout so that I can use match_parent for the relavive layouts without messing up the contents. I am gonna do some testing before saying the isue is fixed. Anyway there is a reason why the layout was working on newer device without issue and causing issue on that os/device?

Comment: I remember that I had the same problem as you with that device. Children layouts seem to not mesure correctly with match_parent if their parents use wrap_content.